# Formatting output from awk command in script

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, awk

If I run this command:

`awk -F'[="]+' '/^(NAME|VERSION)=/{printf("%-17s: %s\n",$1,$2)}' /etc/os-release`

from a terminal, I can retrieve this:

```
NAME             : Debian GNU/Linux
VERSION          : 8 (jessie)
```

(note the formatting/spacing). However, when I try to assign this
command to a local variable and call it, as I do in this function:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#### Display header message ####
# $1 - message

function write_header(){
    local h="$@"
    echo "------------------------------"
    echo "  ${h}"
    echo "------------------------------"
}

#### Get info about Operating System ####

function  os_info(){
    local namevers=$(awk -F'[="]+' '/^(NAME|VERSION)=/{printf("%-17s:    %s\n",$1,$2)}' /etc/os-release)
    write_header "System Info"
    echo "Operating System : $(uname --kernel-name)"               
    echo "Kernel Version   : $(uname --kernel-release)"             
    echo $namevers     
}

os_info
```

My formatting get's mangled (see output after NAME):

```
------------------------------
System Info
------------------------------
Operating System : Linux
Kernel Version   : 3.16.0-4-amd64
NAME : Debian GNU/Linux VERSION : 8 (jessie)
```

I can work around the formatting error by getting rid of the local variable, and calling awk on individual lines like this:

```
awk -F'[="]+' '/^(NAME)=/{printf("%-17s: %s\n",$1,$2)}'    /etc/os-release
awk -F'[="]+' '/^(VERSION)=/{printf("%-17s: %s\n",$1,$2)}' /etc/os-release
```

but that looks a little clunky, and doesn't follow the structure of the larger script I am writing. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Please note: I can't use the `LSB module` because some machines I am testing this script on don't have that package installed. Also, things need to run without elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see the problem in the script:

The variable is being split here:

`echo $namevers`

To fix it, do:

`printf '%s\n' "$namevers"`

Here's the output:

```
------------------------------
    System Info
------------------------------
Operating System : Linux
Kernel Version   : 3.16.0-4-amd64
NAME             : Debian GNU/Linux
VERSION          : 8 (jessie)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, this should produce the output you're after:

```
function  os_info(){
    write_header "System Info"
    echo "Operating System : $(uname --kernel-name)"               
    echo "Kernel Version   : $(uname --kernel-release)"             
    awk -F'[="]+' '/^(NAME|VERSION)=/{printf("%-17s:    %s\n",$1,$2)}' /etc/os-release
}
```

If you really want to use a variable, you need to quote it to preserve the formatting:

```
echo "${namevers}"
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, but that solution does not first assign a local variable to "namevers". As I said, my problem arises when first trying to assign the local variable `namevers` and then later call it in the function.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see you don't need a variable at all!

Comment: But see my edit.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it still mangles the output for me. I think I have an answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

While this answer may not answer your question directly concerning the `awk`kung-fu, you also could just `source` the `/etc/os-release` and use the variables right away.

```
function  os_info() {
    . /etc/os-release
    write_header "System Info"
    echo "Operating System : $(uname --kernel-name)"               
    echo "Kernel Version   : $(uname --kernel-release)"             
    echo "NAME             : $NAME"
    echo "VERSION          : $VERSION"
}
```